# How to re-encode video (avconv) to be compatible with TV set?

Tags: video, avconv

I have two movies with problems watching on a TV. The video has lag and/or the audio is shifted. With `avprobe` I get the following outputs:

```
avprobe version 12.3, Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the Libav developers
  built on Dec 17 2018 21:29:45 with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Input #0, avi, from 'movie1.avi':
  Metadata:
    title           : movie1
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 02:10:03.79, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1174 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 10) [H264 / 0x34363248]
      yuv420p10le, 1920x1040 [PAR 1:1 DAR 24:13], PAR 1:1 DAR 24:13
      23.98 fps, 47.95 tbn
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 [U[0][0][0] / 0x0055]
      48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16p, 128 kb/s
# avprobe output
```

and the second movie:

```
avprobe version 12.3, Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the Libav developers
  built on Dec 17 2018 21:29:45 with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Input #0, avi, from 'movie2.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 01:57:02.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1429 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) [H264 / 0x34363248]
      yuv420p, 1280x692 [PAR 1:1 DAR 320:173], PAR 1:1 DAR 320:173
      23.75 fps, 47.95 tbn
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 [U[0][0][0] / 0x0055]
      48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16p, 128 kb/s
# avprobe output
```

What can I try (with `avconv` etc.) to encode the video so that it might work with the (European) TV set?

Comment: you might want to run them through ffmpeg and dumb them down a little - pick an h264 Main profile as that's got better support. Do they play in sync on your computer? Do you have specs available for what the TV supports? How are you playing it on the TV (built in video player/flash drive, STB, casting etc)?

Comment: What is a main h264 profile? How to do it with `ffmpeg`? Otherwise, I have no specific specs available for the TV, and its with an external hard drive. Usually, all other h264 movies play without any problem.

Comment: do you have an avprobe output from one that works? see https://superuser.com/a/564007